# Updating shared preferences value get fatal signal 6 (SIGABART) error and appcrash

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, opentok, tokbox

Im updating values of shared preferences and I need to recreate() my activity. When recreate() app stop by 5 seconds and after this app close.

I tried create a new Thread but nothing works

```
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x5dc
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] "Thread-23" prio=5 tid=58 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13dc7c58 self=0x77ef2fba00
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=9836 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7809df94f0
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 577906928 11797960 299 ) utm=43 stm=14 core=3 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x7809cff000-0x7809d01000 stackSize=1005KB
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 00000000003aeb84  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 000000000047deac  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00000000002e6280  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 00000000002e683c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+204)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 0000000000482ae4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+548)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 000000000010a894  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+116)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 000000000010b1c0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck12CheckVarArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEPKNS_7VarArgsE+304)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000000000010937c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+860)
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 000000000010eb84  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+132)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #09 pc 000000000010d9f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_listNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+680)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #10 pc 00000000000fb908  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI14CallVoidMethodEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz+184)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #11 pc 00000000000c9048  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #12 pc 00000000000e6f74  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #13 pc 0000000000105ae8  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #14 pc 0000000000112be4  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #15 pc 000000000012add8  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #16 pc 00000000001308a0  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #17 pc 0000000000145694  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #18 pc 000000000014477c  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #19 pc 0000000000143260  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #20 pc 0000000000186128  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #21 pc 000000000014252c  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #22 pc 000000000011fff0  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #23 pc 000000000017b554  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #24 pc 0000000000182280  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #25 pc 0000000000176640  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (uv_run+300)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #26 pc 0000000000120e84  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #27 pc 00000000000e5f40  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #28 pc 000000000006de3c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #29 pc 000000000001f9c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   (no managed stack frames)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] 
    runtime.cc:516] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:516] 
    runtime.cc:524] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x5dc
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:524] "Thread-23" prio=5 tid=58 Runnable
    runtime.cc:524]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13dc7c58 self=0x77ef2fba00
    runtime.cc:524]   | sysTid=9836 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7809df94f0
    runtime.cc:524]   | state=R schedstat=( 577906928 11797960 299 ) utm=43 stm=14 core=3 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:524]   | stack=0x7809cff000-0x7809d01000 stackSize=1005KB
    runtime.cc:524]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #00 pc 00000000003aeb84  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #01 pc 000000000047deac  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #02 pc 00000000002e6280  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #03 pc 00000000002e683c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+204)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #04 pc 0000000000482ae4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+548)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #05 pc 000000000010a894  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+116)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #06 pc 000000000010b1c0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck12CheckVarArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEPKNS_7VarArgsE+304)
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:524]   native: #07 pc 000000000010937c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+860)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #08 pc 000000000010eb84  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+132)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #09 pc 000000000010d9f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_listNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+680)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #10 pc 00000000000fb908  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI14CallVoidMethodEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz+184)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #11 pc 00000000000c9048  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #12 pc 00000000000e6f74  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #13 pc 0000000000105ae8  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #14 pc 0000000000112be4  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #15 pc 000000000012add8  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #16 pc 00000000001308a0  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #17 pc 0000000000145694  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #18 pc 000000000014477c  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #19 pc 0000000000143260  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:524]   native: #20 pc 0000000000186128  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #21 pc 000000000014252c  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #22 pc 000000000011fff0  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #23 pc 000000000017b554  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #24 pc 0000000000182280  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #25 pc 0000000000176640  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (uv_run+300)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #26 pc 0000000000120e84  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #27 pc 00000000000e5f40  /data/app/br.com.wmdirect-2YMrpXOJmAnd6rZqR5VYew==/lib/arm64/libopentok.so (???)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #28 pc 000000000006de3c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+220)
    runtime.cc:524]   native: #29 pc 000000000001f9c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:524]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:524] 
    runtime.cc:524]

---------------------------------------------

A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9836 (Thread-23)
```

---

That is the logcat

Comment: No code - probably it will be closed.

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please more info on when this crash is happening and any reproduction steps?